# Hibernate Batch Fetching to Lazy Loading

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

Currently, I observe in hbernate3, the following behavior.
if I have 
    @BatchSize(size=5)
set, then hibernate will fetch 5 subsets of the mapped type in one SQL query.

If I have 
    .setFetchMode( "set", FetchMode.JOIN );
, then hibernate will eagerly fetch all the subsets of the mapped type ina single SQL query.

However, when I set
    .setFetchMode( "commands", FetchMode.SELECT );
, then hibernate still uses batch fetching, and not lazy fetching.

Is there a way to force hibernate to use lazy fetching when 
    @BatchSize 
is set?

The same question applies to when 
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
is set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to override these settings programmatically, you can consider using @FetchProfile.
Just create a @FetchProfile for an entity:

```
@FetchProfiles({
  @FetchProfile(name = "profileName", fetchOverrides = {
    @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = YourEntity.class, 
                                association = "anAssociation", 
                                mode = FetchMode.JOIN),
...

    })
})
```

and enable that profile in your service/repository method like:

```
session.enableFetchProfile( "profileName" );
```

and your customized fetch settings will work for that session.

Comment: that sounds like what I'm looking for. Can I enable/disable this profile between two transaction within a single session?

Comment: @iliaden Yes you can use Session#disableFetchProfile( profileName ) to disable that in the same session. You can also use Session#isFetchProfileEnabled( profileName ) to find out if a fetch profile is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but **@BatchSize** is used to solve "N+1 problem" but not to ask Hibernate load entities eagerly or lazy. Try to search by keywords: "Hibernate, n+1 problem, batch size".

Comment: I'm aware that it helps resolving the N+1 problem. However, it overwrites the eager/lazy settings. My question is whether it is possible or not ofr these settings to co-exist and be set programmatically.